# sign determination of singular vectors ind matlabs svd function

Tags: matlab, svd

Does anybody know how the sign of the singular vectors resulting from Matlab's `svd` function is determined?

Let:

`B = U*S*V'`

be a valid `svd` decomposition of a real or complex 2-by-2 matrix B, then:

`B = (U*c)*S *(V*c)'`

is also valid, where `c` is a matrix that changes the sign of one or both singular vectors:

`c = diag([1 -1]), diag([-1 1]) or diag([-1 -1])`.

I want to know how Matlab's `svd` algorithm determines the sign of the singular vectors in U and V.

Comment: There is no such thing as sign of a vector. The only thing, which might have sign is a scalar, for example, projection of a vector to an another vector. Is your question about changing all vectors to lie in the same half-space?

Comment: My question is about the well-known sign ambiguity of the svd decomposition ([see here for an example](http://prod.sandia.gov/techlib/access-control.cgi/2007/076422.pdf))

Answer (score 0):

Matlab uses LAPACK's DGESVD implementation for singular value decomposition, which doesn't take into account direction of the resulting vectors. In applications, when SVD is performed, decomposed data is processed and then data is reconstructed back signs make no difference. They became only important, when decomposed data is being analyzed.

One might apply sign correction algorithm after performing SVD with Matlab. But I believe sign correction depends on actual meaning of the data.

In the paper you provided direction is chosen to be the same as the most of the data points. This won't work for data with symmetrical distribution as theoretical direction is zero and sample direction will be random resulting in high numerical instability.

If the goal is just to have numerical stability of the solution, then it would be enough to choose some vector and change all SVD vectors to lie in the same half-space with it.